# Delayed Writes & Implications for Cross-Process Synchronization

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs, splistitem

Simple scenario: **OWSTIMER** creates a new **`SPListItem`**, populates it and calls .**`Update()`**. It then fires an HTTP request over to **`w3wp.exe`** (front-end app-pool) to invalidate an in-memory cache held there. Intermittently, we note that, though the HTTP request is fired **after** the .**`Update()`** call, the new record is sometimes not found (yet) when **`w3wp.exe`** queries the same data.

Key observations:

- This happens only intermittently, when the WRITE (by OWSTIMER) happens immediately before the READ (by `w3wp.exe`)
- The data is always eventually persisted, subsequent refreshes of `w3wp.exe` (even seconds later) always include the new item
- `Dispose` is not called on the parent `SPWeb/SPSite` before the READ by `w3wp.exe`

Is it possible that `SPListItem.Update()` is not entirely synchronous (down to db commit) and that there is a write-delay or transaction isolation at the `SPWeb/SPSite` levels? Even if the data is committed synchronously, it seems it's not made available to other processes (other SPSite instances) until the request that wrote the data completes or properly disposes.

**NOTE**: the `Update()` is happening inside of the `EmailReceived(SPList list, Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPEmailMessage emailMessage, string receiverData)` event of an `SPEmailEventReceiver`, hence why the parent SPWeb/SPSite aren't disposed. If there is indeed transaction isolation at play here, we could change the code to instantiate a new `SPSite/SPWeb` for the WRITE to guarantee that these opjects are disposed before attempting to flush out the cache in `w3wp.exe`.

Comment: Have you disposed all the unmanaged resources, like SPWeb, SPSite, etc. - before your HTTP request?

Comment: No, they haven't been disposed. Is the transaction isolated until the SPWeb, SPSite are disposed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to accept that SharePoint, and its API, are designed for good performance in collaboration and content publishing applications. The object model implementation includes all manner of caching mechanisms and optimizations and logic which may change from version to version.

Normally this is not an issue, but in your case you update some content and then immediately initiate a request to another process, which for all we know may be running on a different physical server. I am not surprised that sometimes it takes a few seconds to catch up.

I think you might need a different design approach. Can you use a list item ItemAdded event to do the cache invalidation? I wonder if that would work better.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We did consider using ItemAdded to invalidate the cache; however, and this is a common misunderstanding, ItemAdded will run in the process that added the item (in this case OWSTIMER) and not in the process where our cache is held (w3wp).